# smooth complex projective variety with non-surjective cycle class map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am looking for a smooth complex projective variety such that the rational cycle class map $$CH^k(X)_\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow H^{2k}(X;\mathbb{Q}),$$ which is defined by sending a closed irreducible subvariety $i:Z \hookrightarrow X$ of codimension k to the image of its fundamental class under the induced map of the inclusion in homology (and using Poincaré Duality to get to cohomology) is not surjective in some degree: 
$$Z \mapsto [Z] \in H_{2(\dim{X}-k)}(Z;\mathbb{Q}) \mapsto i_*([Z]) \in H_{2(\dim{X}-k)}(X;\mathbb{Q}) \simeq H^{2k}(X;\mathbb{Q}).$$
Does anybody have an example in mind?

Comment: It's not completely clear from your question which map you want to be non-surjective. To help potential answerers, can you write it down in standard notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic fact you need to get examples like this is that the image of the cycle class map is contained in the subspace $H^{k,k}(X) \cap H^{2k}(X;\mathbf Q)$ of rational $(k,k)$-forms.

So if $H^2(X;\mathbf Q)$ is not contained in $H^{k,k}(X)$, the cycle class map cannot be surjective. Equivalently, tensoring with $\mathbf C$, if any of the summands $$H^{p,q}(X) \quad (p \neq q, p+q=2k)$$ in the Hodge decomposition of $H^{2k}(X;\mathbf C)$ is nonzero, then the cycle class map is not surjective.

The simplest examples are surfaces with $H^{2,0}(X) \neq 0$, for example $K3$ surfaces or abelian surfaces.